# synchronized access of resource between two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads and a cache. Let's call the thread 1 as Tb, it is a background thread(i.e, has lower priority) and the other thread as Tm(Main thread having higher priority). There is a cache that gets updated by both the threads. You can say that the thread Tb is sort of a helper to Tm for preemptively filling in cache when it can.

The thing is when Tm wants access to cache, it must get immediate access to it because some UI updation display depends on it.

Since the cache is shared for concurrent writing, I have synchronized access to the cache as follows:

```
Element checkAndUpdateCache(int elementPositionToBeChecked){

  Element toBeReturned;

  synchronized(lock){

    // Check if the element is already present in the cache
    if(!cache.hasElement(elementPositionToBeChecked)){

      // If not, retrieve a new one and fill the cache
      toBeReturned = retrieveNewElement(elementPositionToBeChecked);
      cache.put(elementPositionToBeChecked, toBeReturned );
    }
    else{
      toBeReturned = cache.getElement(elementPositionToBeChecked);
    }

  }

  return toBeReturned;

}
```

The problem is that since background thread is calling this method in a loop, it demands very fast continued access to the cache and almost never lets go of the lock. Currently, I am making a call to Thread.yield() after every loop cycle and additionally Thread.sleep(10) to give some access to the main thread.

Having different priorities doesn't really help, nor does calling Thread.yield() at every loop cycle. Thread.sleep() does help somewhat but I think, we would all agree, that is not a good strategy at all. After all, we would want max CPU utilization, right?

Is there some way to ensure that whenever, the main thread needs access to the cache, it readily gets it while the background thread waits for it and resumes the operation a bit later?

**EDIT: Implementation details**

Cache is a `Map<Integer, Album>` for where the key is an `Integer`.

```
public static Album getAlbum(Context context, int position, @NonNull Cursor cursor, @NonNull Map<Integer, Album> cache){

        // Do we have the Album in cache
        Album albumInfo = cache.get(position);

        if(albumInfo == null){

            cursor.moveToPosition(position);

            // Let's cache this Album
            albumInfo = Album.fromMediaStoreCursor(context, cursor);
            cache.put(position, albumInfo);
        }
EDIT 2
        return albumInfo;
    }
```

**EDIT 2**: The background thread loop that is throttling

```
// While we pre-emptively fetch the Albums to cache in the background :)
if (cursorImages != null) {

    for (int i = 0; i < cursorImages.getCount(); i++) {

        synchronized(SnapsboardApplication.getInstance()) {
            AlbumsListCursorAdapter.getAlbum(ListPhotoVideoAlbumsOnDeviceActivity.this,
                i, cursorImages, cache);
        }

        // Keep checking if we have been asked to cancel
        if (isCancelled()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread.yield();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the cache implemented with? If you use a `java.util.concurrent` collection you don't need to synchronize at all.

Comment: Is `Tm` adding data to the cache itself or is it purely a read-access?

Comment: @EJP : Synchronization is required because if one thread found the cache to be empty for pos p and while it is filling the cache, main thread checks the cache for pos p and finds it empty but it is soon about to be full

Comment: @Lothar Tm is also adding data to cache using this method only. I mean, data that is not there for a position will have to be retrieved for the first time by either of the thread. Background thread is just trying to help when it can

Comment: Using `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent()` reduces this to a few lines, removes the need for manual synchronization and increases the throughput since the whole cache isn't locked anymore. Guava's `Cache` is quite nice too.

Comment: @pulp_fiction Your program isn't required to predict the future, or to wait for 'soon' to expire. If the cache is empty at the moment of checking, it's empty. It won't be *next* time if someone has filled it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the complete implementation it's hard to give real good advice but what comes to my mind as a possible solution is to change the map's definition to `Map<Integer, Future<Album>>` and use the `ExecuterService` to retrieve the data to be added to the map. That way, the background thread shouldn't stay too long within the method `retrieveNewElement(elementPositionToBeChecked)` (that I assume to be the reason why your main thread is blocking) and you main thread already gets a result even if the retrieval is not finished, yet. Calling `future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` will return the needed value or will block till the retrieval is finished (or the timeout is reached).

Comment: Okay. Added the implementation details. Let me know if you require any ore detail.

Comment: @pulp_fiction The mentioned loop of the background thread would be helpful because it's the one that seems to be the cause of your problems.

Comment: Okay. Added the loop

Comment: @pulp_fiction You might just try out my solution (should be the one with the least changes to your existing code). If that doesn't work as needed, you can change your map to ConcurrentMap and try Kayaman's (requires Java 8 as a minimum, though).

Comment: Agreed that the time spent would be reduced but what if there is a situation where there is no Future for a position and main thread needs access to it right away. Background thread is still throttling the processing of data retrieval, now in the form of Future. Main thread would require access to this data right away. So, any background processing shall have to be put to wait. I mean, the wait problem is still there fundamentally, isn't?

Comment: @pulp_fiction If you call `executer.submit(...)` you immediately get a `Future` that you put into the map. So the loop over the map will be finished more or less immediately while the ExecuterService is going through the retrievals. So the main thread can access the map and might get a Future that still hasn't its value. When calling `future.get(...)` the main-thread will then wait for the end of the retrieval of the value.

Answer (score 0):

The Thread Tb is a helper for preparing data in background. If you must retain thread Tb, you need a mechanism to notify thread Tb stop / resume work(further more, notify thread Tb which data to prepare).

Ugly, declare a `volatile boolean work`.

Thread Tm. enter `checkAndUpdateCache`,

```
...
work = false;
synchronized(lock) {
    ...
    work = true;
    lock.notify();
}
```

Thread Tb. enter `checkAndUpdateCache`

```
...
synchronized(lock) {
    while (!work) {
        lock.wait();
    }
    ...
}
```

However, I don't think this question is only problem. For example:

- How Tb decide whether to continue prepare data or which data to prepare.
- Is thread Tb / Tm need different function entrance to do different thing.
- Is necessary call `retrieveNewElement` in lock. Maybe `release lock, retrieveNewElement, relock and put` will be better.